# test command doesn't run in Crontab

Tags: unix, ksh

In Ksh shell, my below command runs okay.

```
test "$(($(date +%W)%4))" -eq 2 && echo "yes" > /u/crmprod/test
```

but it doesn't run in crontab using below. How to solve this please?

```
34 00 * * 2 test "$(($(date +%W)%4))" -eq 2 && echo "yes2" > /u/crmprod/test
```

Comment: Do not assume that crontab runs your command-line via ksh (it may use sh or other shell by default). Change your command line to explicitly invoke ksh with the  command-line. Also capture the stderr to a file , not only the stdout.

Answer (score 0):

so, finally I just put the same commands into a file

```
$> cat /u/crmprod/mytest.scr
test "$(($(date +%W)%4))" -eq 2 && echo "yes2" > /u/crmprod/test
```

and in crontab below worked successfully.

```
* * * * * ksh /u/crmprod/mytest.scr
```